# `blkid` shows two swaps, but I only have one in `/etc/fstab`

Tags: swap

I just encrypted my swap file and now after a reboot I see two devices with "swap" listed when I run `blkid`:

```
/dev/loop0: UUID="82a141ee-b1fd-4d52-a1fb-c0690bed732e" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="3c73ab32-331e-47e7-8cb9-79f82ab41f5d" TYPE="swap"
```

Does this mean I have two swap files, one encrypted and one not, or is this normal with encrypted swap?

My `/etc/fstab` only lists one:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=6135b409-f997-4289-895e-a0abb0617c2b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=757B-FF35  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
#/swapfile none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

As does my `/etc/crypttab`:

```
# <target name> <source device>         <key file>      <options>
cryptswap1 /swapfile /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

And `fdisk -lu` lists them both as having `4GiB`:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 4 GiB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 4 GiB, 4294443008 bytes, 8387584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: I believe that's normal. Since the swap-file is a file it must made available as a block-device, that's what `/dev/loop0` is for. `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` uses `/dev/loop0` as it's destination device. But hard to find solid documentation, so I'll leave this as a comment.